# Node js Cron Job running fine on local server but does not start on aws server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron, queue

I have developed a cron job using node js and bull

```
const queue = new bull(queueName, {
      redis: {
        host: redisConf.url,
        port: redisConf.port
      },
      { repeat: { cron: '*/5 * * * *' } }
    })

queue.process(async job => {
        return await myFunction(job.data)
      })
```

It works fine on my local server, so that every 5 minutes I get my job running.

The problem is that, once I deploy the application on my aws ec2 server, the cron does not start, the queue is up and is working fine, doing several tasks except the cron task.

- I have checked the cron service and it is alive.
- I have checked the machine cron logs, and I don't see any error message.

Any ideas?

Comment: Checked syslog and application logs?

Comment: @mokugo-devops yes I did, but there isn't any error... it simply doesn't start